# WebSocket connection failed Insufficient resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, websocket

I am actually learning to code and I'm trying to make a table with tabs linking to each others through ajax (I'm planning to add some transition between them to avoid the blinking caused by classic hyperlinks and it seemed to be the best thing to do, if you think not, please tell me).

But I have a trouble I don't really understand yet : each time I click one of the tabs to navigate, it gets slower and slower to load until I get this error in the console :

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html/ws' failed: Insufficient resources

I'm thinking that's because something is stacking until it's too much, but I don't what's causing this.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Tab1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mytable").load("../ajax/tab1.html", function() {
      // do stuff when new HTML is loaded in `document.body`
      // for example, load CSS
      $.when($.getScript("../voctor.js"), $.get("../css/style.css")).then(function() {
        // do stuff when script and CSS is loaded
      })
    });
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#Tab2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mytable").load("../ajax/tab2.html", function() {
      // do stuff when new HTML is loaded in `document.body`
      // for example, load CSS
      $.when($.getScript("../voctor.js"), $.get("../css/style.css")).then(function() {
        // do stuff when script and CSS is loaded
      })
    });
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#Tab3").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mytable").load("../ajax/tab3.html", function() {
      // do stuff when new HTML is loaded in `document.body`
      // for example, load CSS
      $.when($.getScript("../voctor.js"), $.get("../css/style.css")).then(function() {
        // do stuff when script and CSS is loaded
      })
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I would assume the issue is because your `voctor.js` script opens a new socket connection whenever you change tabs. I'd suggest you only load that script once, when the page loads, and then open the sockets within this script as required. Also, note that your code can by DRY'd up. Use common classes instead of `TabN` ids. Then you can bind a single event handler which works for all tabs, no matter how many there are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that helps me a lot already !
In the future, I might want to use different js and css files that's why I did it like this. Does that mean I have to stick to one js file only if I want to do this tab thing ?
And you're right for the code, I'll re write this as soon as I can.

Comment: In fact I do have a problem if I load the js file once : It does not apply to tabs, only the page when first loading.
And if I add the js file in the header of each html file, the problem is the same with the sockets.
The only time I don't have any trouble is if I $("body").load but I don't understand why... Any idea ?

Comment: In which case I'd suggest you restructure the content of that file so that it doesn't need to constantly need to be reloaded. Without seeing the content of the file we can't really help you debug that. I'd suggest starting a new question if you're struggling with that issue.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually I've posted a more complete question yesterday, but since I've had no answer I thought it would be better to light it up. Here's the post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73704810/troubles-with-load-and-tabs

Answer (score 0):

If that can ever be useful to someone else, I've found the solution by adding  `.unbind()` to my function. I've also DRY'd it up so here's the final code :

```js
$('.tab').unbind().on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var tabHref = $(this).attr('href');
  $("#content").load(tabHref, function() {
    // do stuff when new HTML is loaded in `document.body`
    // for example, load CSS
    $.when($.getScript("../voctor.js"), $.get("../css/style.css"))
      .then(function() {
        // do stuff when script and CSS is loaded
      })
  });
});
```

I realized that each click doubled the previous request, so first click was 1 request, then 2, then 4, then 8 etc... The `unbind()` avoids that.